# Which area is London's Wentworth Street based?

Tags: uk, london

I got an IT position offer in London. The offer sounds quite good, so I am seriously considering accepting it and moving there.

The company info says it is based on the Wenthworth Street.

What kind of area is it, are there lots of IT companies?

Is it an Eastern part of London and how do you call this area?

Comment: Your title says Wentworth but your text says Wenthworth - assume that's a typo?

Comment: To me this isn't about travel. London, geography, real estate yes. Should we really be encouraging questions of what each suburb of Sydney or Auckland is like in case I consider moving into an apartment or share house there when I go home after travelling for instance?

Answer (score 3):

Wentworth Street goes all the way back to the Middle Ages. It was named after the noble "house" of Wentworth, represented in the 17th century by the Earl of Strafford.

http://wiki.casebook.org/index.php/Wentworth_Street

It is now in the oldest part of town called The City. Some have likened it to New York city's Wall St. At any rate, it is a major business center, especially for businesses connected with, or supporting financial operations, although it also has some residences. It is in the"eastern" part of town, although not in the newer "East End."

Comment: Wrong - it's in Tower Hamlets, not the City of London. The financial district does extend a bit beyond the City, but it's outside that too. So it is indeed the East End.

Comment: More specifically, it's Whitechapel.